# Class count without class variable or a better alternative

Tags: python, oop

```
class Base:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.count += 1
```

The `self.__class__.count` allows me to have a separate counter for each subclass. Now this class, which manages these classes, resets `count` for all subclasses of `Base` and `Base` itself every time it is initialised.

```
class UseMe:
    def __init__(self):
        Base.count = 0
        for cls in Base.__subclasses__():
            cls.count = 0
        self.children: List[Child] = []  # Child is a subclass of Base
```

This solves the problem of multiple instances of `UseMe`:

```
obj = UseMe()
obj.children.append(Child())
Child.count # 1
obj2 = UseMe()
obj2.children.append(Child())
Child.count # 1
```

However, this isn't what I want

```
obj = UseMe()
obj.children.append(Child())
Child.count # 1
obj2 = UseMe()
obj.children.append(Child())
Child.count # 1 !!!?
```

This example is oversimplified, I might have missed some detail, but the problem is valid.

I am using `count` to stop the creation of additional classes after a particular limit.

**TLDR;** I want to keep `count` "global" to an instance of `UseMe`.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to ``count``? What is "the problem of multiple instances of ``UseMe``" that the resetting is supposed to solve? In the second case, what *other* result do you want and why?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `UseMe`resets **all** children of the Base class to 0:

```
for cls in Base.__subclasses__():
            cls.count = 0
```

Maintain a list in `Base` by passing `UseMe.count` to `Base`:

```
from typing import List


class UseMe:
    useCount = -1 
    def __init__(self):
        UseMe.useCount += 1
        self.count = UseMe.useCount # instance counter

        Base.count.append(0); #Add slot for count of child to the list
        self.children: List[Child] = []  # Child is a subclass of UseMe

class Base:
    count = []

    def __init__(self, um):
        self.um = um.count # store parent
        self.__class__.count[um.count] += 1 # add 1 at the parent's UseMe
class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, um):
        Base.__init__(self,um) 
        self.count = Base.count[um.useCount]

obj = UseMe()
obj.children.append(Child(obj))
print(len(obj.children)) #1
print(obj.children[len(obj.children)-1].count) # [1]
obj2 = UseMe()
obj.children.append(Child(obj))
print(len(obj.children)) # 2
print(obj.children[len(obj.children)-1].count) # [2,0]
obj3 = UseMe()
obj.children.append(Child(obj))
obj3.children.append(Child(obj3))

print(obj3.children[len(obj3.children)-1].count[obj3.children[len(obj3.children)-1]])
# 1 since Base.count is: [2,0,1]
```

Child instance *could* be assigned to multiple lists.